# Look up value from one dataframe and find percent of values in another dataframe that are less than that

Tags: r

Is there a one-liner that can accomplish this same thing? Essentially I have two dataframes: one that has my raw data (`data`), and one that has values that I want to lookup (`lookup`). I want to find the percent of values in `data` (by 2 factors, `Site` and `variable`) that are less than the `lookup` value for those same 2 factors.

I'd love to just be able add the result to the `lookup` dataframe as a column, instead of creating two new objects.

```
combine <- merge(data, lookup, by = c("Site", "variable"), allow.cartesian = TRUE)
test <- ddply(combine, .(Site, variable), summarize, percent = sum(data.values < lookup.value) / length(data.values))
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to encapsulate the `ddply` logic, you can use the `lapply(split(data, data[ , c("Site", "variable") ], function)`-approach. I'm assuming that lookup only has one "value" for each combination of "Site" and "variable". Something like:

```
lapply( split(data, data[ , c("Site", "variable") ]), 
       function(d) { percent= 100*sum(d$value)/ lookup[
                                   lookup$Site==d$Site[1] lookup$variable==d$variable[1] ,
                                       "value"]}
       )
```

Another approach (only successful if the factor levels in both dataframes match) would be to use the quotient of two `tapply`-(matrix) results from each dataframes:

```
 percent= 100*tapply( data$value, data[ , c("Site", "variable")] , sum, na.rm=TRUE)/
 tapply( lookup$value, lookup[ , c("Site", "variable")] , sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```